# Exporting to PDF: Multiple feature classes with similar names as separate PDFs

Tags: layers, export, pdf

I have a list of feature classes used as facilities in network analysis to find out walking and cycling time. So for example, schools, hospitals, pharmacies etc. I therefore want to export a PDF with the schools plus the study area, hospitals plus the study area etc. as separate PDFs for each facility and associated analysis:

```py
import arcpy

#Get the MXD
m = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

#Get the data frame
d = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(m, "")[0]

#Get the layer list in the data frame
ls = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(m, "", d)

#Set layer dictionary
layer_dict = {"layer_name" : ["turn_on_lyr_1", "turn_on_lyr_2"]}

#Get the folder you want to save your PDF files into
PDFPath = r'C:\Users\Charlie-x.Churchill\Documents\PyTrial'

#Create empty list
layerList = []

#add layer names to the list
for l in ls:
    layerList.append(l.name)

for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(m, '',d):
    for lname in layerList:
      if lname in layer_dict:
           for    lyr in layer_dict[layer_name]: lyr.visible = True
           lyr.visible = True
           arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
           arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(m, PDFPath + "\\" + lyr.name + ".PDF")
           lyr.visible = False

del m
```